# querySelectorAll returning an empty nodelist

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

This code worked before some DOM changes, but now JavaScript doesn't add or remove the `active` class to the clicked star element. In the snippet, the code seems to run without any problem but when I use `console.log (stars);` I see that it returns an empty `NodeList []` in my browser and that explains why it doesn't add/remove the `active` class to the clicked element (I don't really know how to provide a reproducible code here). By the way, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element), I write `<script src="script-landing.js" defer></script>` at the end of the `<body>` tag element so that  the script is loaded after the DOM elements.

I really need help in finding out what is wrong here and  I appreciate any hint.

I used this JavaScript  code which worked for a star rating box:

```js
//Star Rating Box
//Select all elements with the "i" tag and store them in a NodeList called "stars"
const stars = document.querySelectorAll("[data-star]");
console.log(stars);

//Loop through the "stars" NodeList
stars.forEach((star, index1) => {
  //Add an event listener that runs a function when the "click" event is triggered
  star.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //Loop through the "stars" NodeList Again
    stars.forEach((star, index2) => {
      // Add the "active" class to the clicked star and any stars with a lower index
      // And remove the "active" class from any stars with a higher index
      index1 >= index2 ?
        star.classList.add("active") :
        star.classList.remove("active");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.stars-rating-landing i {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.stars-rating-landing i.active {
  color: #ff9c1a;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-box-landing">
  <header>Rate this book</header>
  <div class="stars-rating-landing">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-star" data-star></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-star" data-star></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-star" data-star></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-star" data-star></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-star" data-star></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As demonstrated in the runnable snippet, the elements can be found fine in the code you provided. We'll need a [mcve] to be able to tell you what the problem is. (Though, if I have to guess, I'd say [the script is loaded in before the elements are part of the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).)

Comment: If your code runs before the DOM is built, it won't find anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ivar I see it works on the snippet, but on my console there is an empty node list. I wrote <script src="script-landing.js" defer></script> at the end of the <body> tag element. And from when star rating box worked, I have not changed it's place. I hope I got you correctly

Comment: I pasted the <script src="script-landing.js" defer></script> before the <body> tag (inside <head> tag) and nothing changed for me.